# Powershell while loop

Tags: powershell, if-statement, while-loop

The below code keeps getting stuck in a loop when it gets to

```
$choice = read-host "Are you sure you want to disable the following user? (Y/N)" "$name"
```

I type in y and it keeps looping that question.

I've tried a do while & single IF statement. Any ideas on how to stop this loop?

```
$choice = ""
$User = read-host "enter username"
$Name = Get-ADuser -Identity $Username | Select-Object Name

while ($choice -notmatch "y/n"){
    $choice = read-host "Are you sure you want to disable the following user? (Y/N)" "$name"

    If ($Choice -eq"Y"){
        Disable-ADAccount $Username
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the pipe for an or statement to work not a slash

This...

```
while ($choice -notmatch "y/n"
```

...should be this...

```
while ($choice -notmatch "y|n"
```

This is wrong, because you do not have a populated variable in the posted code to use...

```
Disable-ADAccount $Username
```

... based on your code, it should be this...

```
Disable-ADAccount $User
```

No need to seperate the variable in the choice statment. Just do this.

```
$choice = read-host "Are you sure you want to disable the following user? (Y or N) $name"
```

Example:

```
$choice = ""
$User = read-host "enter username"
$Name = $User

while ($choice -notmatch "y|n")
{
    $choice = read-host "Are you sure you want to disable the following user? (Y/N) $Name"

    If ($Choice -eq "y")
    { $User } 
}

enter username: test
Are you sure you want to disable the following user? (Y/N) test: u
Are you sure you want to disable the following user? (Y/N) test: u
Are you sure you want to disable the following user? (Y/N) test: y
test


enter username: test1
Are you sure you want to disable the following user? (Y/N) test1: h
Are you sure you want to disable the following user? (Y/N) test1: h
Are you sure you want to disable the following user? (Y/N) test1: n
```

Comment: My two pennies: `while ($choice -notin "y", "n") {...` is simpler and easier to understand